# How to get time at current location (from internet)

Tags: android, date, time

Possisble duplicate:

[Get Data from the internet android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466342/get-data-from-the-internet-android)

Hi all,
I'm developing an app, it can get real time at current location. My idea is get from internet, but i don't know how to got it. I had latitude and longitude from current location.

My questions:

1. How to get real time at current location (longitude and latitude are avaiable)
2. Tutorial or Source Code

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I get it from somewhere

I think it is not possible directly from android SDK. You can get a 
    timezone from a city name, but not from lat/long values (see 
    https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html 
    `setID() and getAvailableIDs()` )

You can make a request to a webservice that will give you the time 
    zone from lat/long. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city 
    for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get time for the current location but for this you have to  set the system's persistent default time zone.`setTimeZone(String timeZone)` which can be get from

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
 TimeZone current = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

`setAutoTimeEnabled(boolean enabled)`

Sets whether or not wall clock time should sync with automatic time updates from NTP.

```
TimeManager timeManager = TimeManager.getInstance();
 // Use 24-hour time
 timeManager.setTimeFormat(TimeManager.FORMAT_24);

 // Set clock time to noon
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
 long timeStamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
 timeManager.setTime(timeStamp);
```

I was looking for that type of answer I read your answer but didn't satisfied and it was bit old. I found the new solution and share it. :)

For more information visit: https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager.html

Comment: This is misleading, your code is just get current time from system, not from internet (out source)