# Retrieving the current date and time from a time server

Tags: android, date, time

In my Android app, I would like to retrieve the current date/time (UTC) from some server. Android does have the built-in ability to synchronize the device's date and time with some server but I have found this to be unreliable. Does Google or some other well known service provider provide a simple API that would allow me to retrieve the current date/time? I am not interested in trying to set the date/time on the device (that's not even possible). But I do need to know the correct date in order to perform scheduled tasks that depend on exact dates.

I have seen a device reset its date to something like 1980 when the battery has been removed for an extended period of time and therefore I cannot rely upon the date of the device.

EDIT:

I came across this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066268/753632

But it requires installing Apache Commons Net. Kind of overkill just to get the time. I don't need to bloat my code more than it already is.

Comment: This works and is lightweight.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9466443/753632

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link [How can I get the "network" time, (from the "Automatic" setting called "Use network-provided values"), NOT the time on the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw)

Answer (score -2):

You could use the calender class, like is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date), although this uses the time of the device itself. You could also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278663/how-to-get-time-from-server-in-android) it explains how to get the time for the service provider.

I think using the calender and then calculating the UTC time with based on the timezone the phone is in (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672597/how-to-get-timezone-from-android-mobile)). Because the phone already gets it's time from a server when it is connected to the internet.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: I see you edited your post. So you don't want to use the device time... I think you could look into getting it from the service provider then.

Comment: I didn't edit the post. I edited the title. The post always stated "from some server".

Comment: Yeah, but you also stated you tried getting it "from some server" and said that it didn't work. I only tried to give you some other options.

Comment: "with some server but I have found this to be unreliable". Unreliable == does not work

Comment: *Android* has a problem with synchronizing the system date with a server.