# get current Date from internet in android

Tags: android, date, datetime, android-asynctask

I want to know if there is any API/class in android which can give us the original date as I do not want to get the date/time from android device.

Comment: No, there is nothing like that in Android.

Comment: this might help   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java

Comment: You can use any third-party service or you can write a webservice to get hat

Comment: No, instead use web services.

Answer (score 7):

Updated!!

The old answer does not work because the timeapi.org is down.

Here is the my new getTime method. It's using **JSOUP**.

```
private long getTime() throws Exception {
    String url = "https://time.is/Unix_time_now";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
    String[] tags = new String[] {
            "div[id=time_section]",
            "div[id=clock0_bg]"
    };
    Elements elements= doc.select(tags[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <tags.length; i++) {
        elements = elements.select(tags[i]);
    }
    return Long.parseLong(elements.text());
}
```

To convert timestamp into readable date and time

```
private String getDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
public String getTime() {
try{
    //Make the Http connection so we can retrieve the time
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // I am using yahoos api to get the time
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new
    HttpGet("http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo"));
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        // The response is an xml file and i have stored it in a string
        String responseString = out.toString();
        Log.d("Response", responseString);
        //We have to parse the xml file using any parser, but since i have to 
        //take just one value i have deviced a shortcut to retrieve it
        int x = responseString.indexOf("<Timestamp>");
        int y = responseString.indexOf("</Timestamp>");
        //I am using the x + "<Timestamp>" because x alone gives only the start value
        Log.d("Response", responseString.substring(x + "<Timestamp>".length(),y) );
        String timestamp =  responseString.substring(x + "<Timestamp>".length(),y);
        // The time returned is in UNIX format so i need to multiply it by 1000 to use it
        Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp) * 1000);
        Log.d("Response", d.toString() );
        return d.toString() ;
    } else{
        //Closes the connection.
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
}catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
}catch (IOException e) {
Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: and u can just take a look on this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466342/get-data-from-the-internet-android

Answer (score 0):

You can get time from internet time servers using the below program

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.commons.net.time.TimeTCPClient; 

    public final class GetTime { 

        public static final void main(String[] args) {
            try { 
                TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
                try { 
                    // Set timeout of 60 seconds 
                    client.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
                    // Connecting to time server 
                    // Other time servers can be found at : http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi# 
                    // Make sure that your program NEVER queries a server more frequently than once every 4 seconds 
                    client.connect("nist.time.nosc.us");
                    System.out.println(client.getDate());
                } finally { 
                    client.disconnect();
                } 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } 
    }
```

1.You would need Apache Commons Net library for this to work. Download the library and add to your project build path.

(Or you can also use the trimmed Apache Commons Net Library here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjxjv7phkb8xfhh/commons-net-3.1.jar. This is enough to get time from internet )

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [android.net.sntp.SntpClient](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/SntpClient.java/) class.

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
int timeout = 50000;
if (client.requestTime("time-a.nist.gov", timeout)) {
    long time = client.getNtpTime();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    calendar.getTime();  // this should be your date
}
```