# Get REAL date and time from internet in android studio

Tags: android

First of all, I know that there are many questions like mine. However, I cannot understand that solutiona or they just doesn't work. So, I don't need the date and time from DEVICE. I need the real date and time in the Asia/Tashkent. Also i tried the way with

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance():
```

This one shows device date and time too. In other words I need the date which user will not be able to manipulate by changing device date. At least just advice some useful APIs e.t.c.
I know that there is a lot of such kind questions. Also, please, explain which part of the code is used for what.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30323630/10239396) seems simple to me. Give it a try.

Comment: There is no such class as HttpClient, this class is used in the solution you sent me, what should i do?

Comment: ApacheHttp Client is removed in API 23. You can use 3rd party like OkHttp.

Comment: In simple words, you can get the time from an online API service such as [TimeAPI](http://timeapi.com) and convert it to whatever you want.

Comment: So tell me some API as TimeAPI is being for sale

Comment: Does that include UTC+5(Asia/Tashkent) timezone? Please help me. Is there some detailed documentation on using this api?

Comment: You can go [here](https://timezonedb.com/references/get-time-zone). There's a usage example right there that you can try.